# extract specific fields and combine into 1 text file with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use `perl` to extract specific fields from all text files in a directory output that to one new file, with each text file on a new line.

**input**

```
#Sample = xxxxx
#Sample Type = xxxxxx
#Build = xxxxxxx
#Platform = xxxxxxx
#Display Name= XXXXX  (keep this field without the #)
#identifier = xxxxxx  (keep this field without the #)
#Gender = xxxxx       (keep this field without the #)
#Control Gender = xxxxx
#Control Sample = xxxxx
#Quality = X.XXXXXX   (keep this field without the # and X.XXX)
```

**desired output** (fields to keep from each text file)

```
Display Name= XXXXX  (keep this field without the #)
identifier = xxxxxx  (keep this field without the #)
Gender = xxxxx       (keep this field without the #)
```

I took @Borodin suggestion in an earlier post and tried a script to accomplish this that I think is close:

**perl**

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
perl -ne '(s/^#(Display Name|identifier|Gender)/$1/ or s/^#(Quality = \d\.\d{3})\d+/$1/) and print' *.txt > all.txt
perl "C:\cygwin\home\get_all_qc2.pl"
syntax error at C:\cygwin\home\get_all_qc2.pl line 3, near "-ne"
Execution of C:\cygwin\home\get_all_qc2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Thank you :).

Comment: did you write command-line perl invocations in your perl script???

Comment: Do you know any Perl?

Comment: yes, I call it with `perl "C:\cygwin\home\get_all.pl"'  Thank you :).

Comment: That's interesting considering that the file is called `get_all_qc2.pl`, not `get_all.pl`.

Comment: I changed the name of the `.pl` but that is not causing the error... even if I change it back I get a syntax error... I know some `perl` though I am still learning it.  Its probably a simple mistake but its how I learn.  Thank you :).

Comment: `perl -ne  '...'` is a shell command, not a Perl statement. You can't just put bare shell commands into a Perl program and expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment, I appreciate it :).

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes, just trying to learn... thank you.

Comment: @Chris sorry about all the downvotes, working on an answer

Comment: @Pro Blaster thank you, I am a scientist learning programming as it relates to my field. I started with `awk, sed, and bash`. `perl` is a bit new to me but is used a lot in the medical genetics. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to start with, if you're running this code as a script from inside a `.pl` file, you're doing it wrong. What you've done is written the shell invocation of a Perl one-liner into your file and expected it to execute as Perl code!

So, to start, we change your file to something like this:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
s/^#(Display Name|identifier|Gender)/$1/ or s/^#(Quality = \d\.\d{3})\d+/$1/) and print;
```

And then we just invoke it with `perl file.pl`.

But that doesn't actually do what you want.

So, instead, we do something like this:

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict; # Good Perl practice to use these, always

my $file = $ARGV[0]; # Grabs the filename from the cmdline arguments
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!"; # Opens the file

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ /\#(?:((?:Display Name|Identifier|Gender) = .+)|(Quality =))/; # Match and capture your desired elements
    print $1 if ($1); # If we found anything, print it
}

close $fh;
```

Then we execute it with `perl file.pl input.txt`, sit back, and let it run.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Lenartowicz... I am familiar with a shell environment and that was part of my issue along with how to best use a `perl` approach. I really appreciate your help and explanations :)